# I need to make a sql

Tags: sql, syntax, client

**

```
SELECT clientName, orderID FROM
Orders INNER JOIN clients ON orders.clientID = clients.clientID;
```

**

I can show every client and each of their orders. Help me correct my SQL syntax, so I am showing the number of orders for each client?

I also want my results to be ordered alphabetically by client name,

please write a new SQL syntax for me!

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `COUNT()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select c.clientName, count(*) no_orders
from clients c
inner join orders o on o.clientID = c.clientID
group by c.clientID, c.clientName
```

Notes:

- table aliases make the query easier to read and write
- adding the id of the client to the `group by` clause handles the possibility that different clients might have the same name
- in general, you want to avoid camel case identifiers (`ClientName`) and use snake case instead (`client_name`): from database perspective, identifiers are case insensitive (unless quoted)

Comment: What is o and c for?

Comment: And why is it no_orders even I want to make is by order?

Comment: @userman: these are table aliases, as explained in my answer. And `no_orders` is a column alias, which would stand for *number of orders*.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT clientName, COUNT(*)
FROM Orders INNER JOIN clients ON orders.clientID = clients.clientID
GROUP BY clientName
ORDER BY clientName